# Image rotating in image view but not actually raotaing on debugging image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to rotate image and using following code.

```
switch (_adjustedImage.imageOrientation)
{
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        _adjustedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: _adjustedImage.CGImage
                                                    scale: 1.0
                                              orientation: UIImageOrientationDown];
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
        _adjustedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: _adjustedImage.CGImage
                                                    scale: 1.0
                                              orientation: UIImageOrientationLeft];
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        _adjustedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: _adjustedImage.CGImage
                                                    scale: 1.0
                                              orientation: UIImageOrientationUp];
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
        _adjustedImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: _adjustedImage.CGImage
                                                    scale: 1.0
                                              orientation: UIImageOrientationRight];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

But on debugging the adjusted image the `_adjustedImage` is not rotated, but updated on image view so on saving the image the image is in same orientation as before.